# POI fails to write to excel because DefaultMarshaller

Tags: java, apache, glassfish, apache-poi, payara

The goal is to export a excel file through a REST backend implemented with Jersey, deployed in Payara (Glassfish).

When data exceeds 50 customers I receive an error. POI fails because of DefaultMarshaller.
Could I exchange the Default Marshaller with a better Marshaller ? Can this be configured in Payara ?

```
public Response exportCustomers(CustomerFilterRequest filter, String locale) {

    List<CustomerEntity> customers = getPagingCustomerEntities(null, filter).getElements();

    StreamingOutput streamingOutput = outputStream -> {
        Workbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("Customers");

        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workBook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        headerCellStyle.setFont(font);
        headerCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        CellStyle dataCellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
        font = workBook.createFont();
        dataCellStyle.setFont(font);
        dataCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        ExportTable exportTable = new ExportTable(sheet, HEADER, headerCellStyle, dataCellStyle);


        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            CustomerEntity customer = customers.get(i);
            exportTable.createDataRow();

            exportTable.addData(customer.getId());
            exportTable.addData(customer.getLastName());
            exportTable.addData(customer.getFirstName());
        }

        ExportUtils.autoResizeColumns(sheet);
        **workBook.write(outputStream);** . -----> LINE THAT FAILS 
    };

    return Response.ok(streamingOutput, FileType.XLSX.toMimeType()).build();
}


private Sheet sheet;
private Row row;
private Cell cell;
private CellStyle dataCellStyle;
private String[] headers;
private int rowIndex = 0;
private int columnIndex = 0;

public ExportTable(Sheet sheet, String[] headerColumns, CellStyle headerCellStyle, CellStyle dataCellStyle) {
    this.sheet = sheet;
    headers = headerColumns;
    this.dataCellStyle = dataCellStyle;
    row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(headers[i]);
        cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
    }
}

public void createDataRow() {
    columnIndex = 0;
    row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
}

public void addData(String value) {
    cell = row.createCell(columnIndex++);
    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
}

public void addData(Integer value) {
    cell = row.createCell(columnIndex++);
    cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
}

public void createEmptyCell() {
    cell = row.createCell(columnIndex++);
    cell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK);
    cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
      [2018-10-18T13:18:09.415+0000] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(4)] [timeMillis: 1539868689415] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@4ecabb27
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)     at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:598)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@4ecabb27     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:595)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1539)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
        at
    com.bmwgroup.sfm.conf.GzipWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GzipWriterInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
        at com.bmwgroup.sfm.security.ClientEncryptionInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(ClientEncryptionInterceptor.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@4ecabb27
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:586)
        ... 62 more
    ]]
```

LE

```
[2018-10-22T08:13:51.703+0000] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPartMarshaller] [tid: ThreadID=43 ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1540196031703] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Cannot write: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml: in ZIP
java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:445)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:677)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleWrite(SSLBaseFilter.java:395)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:858)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1060)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:1047)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:1017)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:139)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:684)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:728)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:343)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:84)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPartMarshaller.marshallRelationshipPart(ZipPartMarshaller.java:180)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPartMarshaller.marshall(ZipPartMarshaller.java:104)
... 65 more
]]

[2018-10-22T08:13:51.704+0000] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder] [tid: ThreadID=43 ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1540196031704] [levelValue: 1000] [[
An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@5cea6d26
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@5cea6d26
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:595)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1539)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:78)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
... 47 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@5cea6d26
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:586)
... 62 more
]]
```

Comment: The main problem is `The part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml failed to be saved in the stream` which means `PackagePart` `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` cannot be written in your `outputstream`. So main question is where is your `outputstream` coming from and why is it not ready fro writing? Try enabling [Apache POI - Logging Framework](https://poi.apache.org/components/logging.html) and you will probably get "Cannot write: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml: in ZIP" together with an `IOException`. This `IOException` might point you to the reason why writing in your `outputstream` fails.

Comment: Do you think that I lack rights on a temporary folder where a temporary result might be saved ?

Comment: All wild assumptions will lead to nothing. Fact is your `outputstream` is not ready for writing. Try determining why.

Comment: I updated the full stacktrace

Comment: Again: Where is `outputstream` coming from? The `java.io.IOException: Connection is closed` ... `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` seems pretty clear pointing to the issue that there is a TCP connection closed which should not be closed. Maybe any timeout occured?